# Aparecen mensajes en la terminal de vs code

Tags: vscode, terminal

al ejecutar mi programa me aparece este mensaje en la terminal y me parece muy molesto. ¿cómo puedo eliminar estos mensajes?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una opción podria ser instalarte la extensión macros y automatizarte "ejecutar y cerrar la terminal"

Answer (score 1):

Cuándo ejecutas tu código lo que realmente haces es indicarle a VSCode que utilice la terminal integrada para correr tu código, en este caso usa PowerShell de Microsoft.

El primer mensaje en blanco que ves es de power shell, puedes presioanr `win+R` y escribir `powershell` para invocar la consola y vas a ver cada vez que invocas la consola te sale el mismo mensaje.

VSCode hace esto para poder llamar al interprete de Python para que pueda correr tu código. Lo qué ves en letras azules son 3 ejecuciones de código para que puedas correr tu código, la primera llama al interprete de python y por eso termina en `/python.exe`; la segunda se encarga de llamar la extensión de VSCode para que puedas debuggear cosas en el IDE y la tercera finalmente ejecuta tu código que esta guardado en el archivo `app.py`.

Estos no son mensajes, si no que son la manera en la que VSCode ejecuta tu código, no son opcionales. Una manera sencilla de evitar verlos sería importar el módulo del sistema operativo y limpiar la pantalla, entonces cuando VSCode ejecute los comandos y entre a tu código borre lo que está escrito en la consola, ocuparías estas dos líneas de código al inicio de tu archivo `app.py`:

```
from os import system 

system('clear')
```

La primera importa el módulo para poder usar la terminal, utilízala con las demás importaciones  de módulos (las que dicen import) y si no tienes ninguna importación, asegúrate de que sea la primera línea en tu código.

La segunda línea limpia la consola, ubicala al inicio de tu código, antes de que se ejecute cualquier otra cosa.

Lo único malo que podría pasar es que no puedas ver una advertencia/error del interprete o de la extensión de VSCode al tratar de ejecutar tu código, ya que bse borrará el mensaje de advertencia en la consola. Aunque es poco probable porque si se borra la consola es porque tu código ya está siendo ejecutado.

Suerte en tu programación!

Comment: Agradezco la detallada explicación, me pareció muy completa, Igual se aprecia la ayuda a principiantes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Cerrar la ventana presionando el icono X desde el lado derecho de esa ventana o simplemente matar el terminal presionando sobre el icono basurero. Si quieres recuperar la ventana terminal, desde el Menú de herramientas elije: Terminal -> New Terminal.

De lo contrario, si solo quieres limpiar el texto, solo escribe CLEAR y das enter para que limpie todo el texto y deje la terminal limpia.

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario> CLEAR <enter>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la contestación!